# Can you configure the IMAP client to connect via a proxy?

Tags: proxy, mailkit

Can you configure the IMAP client in mailkit to connect via a proxy? if so, how? I'm guessing it would have to be a socks proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Each of MailKit's *Client implementations has a `Connect` method that takes a `Socket`. This is how you'd connect via a proxy.

First, you'd open a `Socket` and connect it to your proxy, send the appropriate commands, and then pass that socket off to MailKit.